# JAVA_HOME versus java -version

Tags: centos, centos6, java, centos7

I've two JDK's on my CentOS machine, 1.7 and 1.8.

When I set my `JAVA_HOME` to 1.7 the `java -version` command still shows 1.8

What's this? And how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you run `java`. If you run `java -version` without specifying any path, the *first* `java` executable found in `$PATH` environment variable is used. This has nothing to do with `JAVA_HOME` var.

If you want to change the java executable you are using based on changing the `JAVA_HOME` var, you can run it:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you also remember to change the location of the Java binaries in your path (environment)? You will still need to edit your

.bash_profile:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7_92`

or

/etc/environment:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7_92
export JAVA_HOME`

(whichever way Centos supports setting the path at login) to point to the JDK (or JRE) you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a java symbolic link is put under /usr/bin directory for java. You can see that by issuing "`which java`" command. You can try to change it if you have a root password, if you can't you may try to call java binary directly, like;

```
/home/myhome/jdk7/bin/java -version
```

IMO that should do the work.

Comment: You can check the symbolic links i.e via `ll -h /etc/alternatives/java` and `ll -h /usr/java`, which might give better insight then.